# How to query Wikidata using SPARQL using entity names and also check alternative labels?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to query Wikidata using entity names. My goal is to get the Wikidata ID of the entity. Right now I have something like:

```
SELECT ?item
WHERE {
    ?item rdfs:label "name_of_thing"@en
}
```

and while this usually gets the job done I also want to check whether the label is contained in the alternative names on Wikidata.

For example, if I replace `"name_of_thing"` with `"Philippines AirAsia"` then I don't get any results, but the reason why is because `"AirAsia Philippines"` is the proper name of the entry, with `"Philippines AirAsia"` contained in the "Also known as" column in the Wikidata page.

I want to query the page and if the first fetch fails then check whether the name is contained in the "Also known as" column. How should I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: without precedence, it would simply be `SELECT ?item
WHERE {
    ?item rdfs:label|skos:altLabel "Philippines AirAsia"@en
}` - with precedence things are getting more complicated, maybe something like `SELECT (COALESCE(?item1, ?item2) as ?item)
WHERE {
    {?item1 rdfs:label "Philippines AirAsia"@en } UNION {?item2 skos:altLabel "Philippines AirAsia"@en}
}` - I didn't check if it really works for multiple matches.

Comment: maybe [something like this](https://w.wiki/33Hv) is sufficient:
`SELECT ?item ?prefLabel ?altLabel
WHERE {
    values ?prefLabel {"AirAsia Philippines"@en}
    ?item rdfs:label ?prefLabel ;
    skos:altLabel ?altLabel .
}`

Answer (score 1):

The pipe operator works for me:

[Query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FprefLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20values%20%3FprefLabel%20%7B%22AirAsia%20Philippines%22%40en%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%7Cskos%3AaltLabel%20%3FprefLabel.%0A%7D)

```
SELECT ?item ?prefLabel WHERE {
        VALUES ?prefLabel { "AirAsia Philippines"@en }
        ?item rdfs:label|skos:altLabel ?prefLabel 
}
```